# What does md-error and md-invalid mean in vuematerial?

Tags: vue.js, vue-material, vuelidate

There is no documentation on these classes in [vue-material](https://vuematerial.io/getting-started). Where these classes come from and how are they related to vuelidate?
I am trying to write client side validation. The form validation example in above link is also not working.

Currently vue-material is in beta releases of 1.0. What is the schedule for the GA release of vue-material 1.0 ?

Comment: I guess that is is part of the unfinished advanced theme usage documentation, here's a working example: codepen.io/Samuellsk/pen/aqRejo from github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1511. To be honest, I stopped using this ui framework as I felt that it was not yet mature enough to be used in my own production setting. That being said it has great potential and started out with just Marcos and although he is a very smart guy and has done very much so far there is still a lot that needs to be done. I'd suggest you try to understand the project source so you can potentially make a contribution